# Returning concatenated string as global variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

So here is the code I am using :

```
    global output_res
    output_res = ""

    def recurse(left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
        spacer = spacer_base * depth
        if (threshold[node] != -2):
            """print(spacer + "if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                str(threshold[node]) + " ) {")"""
            output_res += spacer + "if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                str(threshold[node]) + " ) {"
            if left[node] != -1:
                recurse (left, right, threshold, features, left[node], depth+1)
            """print(spacer + "}\n" + spacer +"else {")"""
            output_res += spacer + "}\n" + spacer +"else {"
            if right[node] != -1:
                recurse (left, right, threshold, features, right[node], depth+1)
            """print(spacer + "}")"""
            output_res += spacer + "}"
        else:
            target = value[node]
            for i, v in zip(np.nonzero(target)[1], target[np.nonzero(target)]):
                target_name = target_names[i]
                target_count = int(v)
                """print(spacer + "return " + str(target_name) + " ( " + \
                    str(target_count) + " examples )")"""
                output_res += spacer + "return " + str(target_name) + " ( " + \
                    str(target_count) + " examples )"

        return output_res

    recurse(left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)
```

As you can see `recurse()` is a recursive function, my aim is to to retrieve the `output_res`, and use it in the main function, using this code I am having this error :

> local variable 'output_res' referenced before assignment

**Update**

I found the exact solution for what I am looking for :

```
            temp_list = []
            def recurse(temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
                spacer = spacer_base * depth
                if (threshold[node] != -2):
                    temp_list.append(spacer + "if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                        str(threshold[node]) + " ) {")
                    if left[node] != -1:
                            recurse (temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, left[node], depth+1)
                    temp_list.append(spacer + "}\n" + spacer +"else {")
                    if right[node] != -1:
                            recurse (temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, right[node], depth+1)
                    temp_list.append(spacer + "}")
                else:
                    target = value[node]
                    for i, v in zip(np.nonzero(target)[1], target[np.nonzero(target)]):
                        target_name = target_names[i]
                        target_count = int(v)
                        temp_list.append(spacer + "return " + str(target_name) + " ( " + \
                            str(target_count) + " examples )")

            recurse(temp_list, left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)
            return '\n'.join(temp_list)
```

Comment: cant you call your function output_res = recurse(output_res, left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you really want to go with global variable

```
output_res = ""

def recurse(left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
    global output_res
    //your code
    //no need to do "return output_res"

recurse(left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)
```

Explanation:

```
In [8]: myG = 5

In [9]: def fun1():
   ...:     myG=45
   ...: 

In [10]: def fun2():
   ....:     print myG

In [11]: fun1()

In [12]: fun2()
5 //output

//Now change the fun1 with global
In [15]: def fun1():
   ....:    global myG
   ....:    myG=45

In [17]: fun1()

In [18]: fun2()
45 //output, this explains how global affects the scope
```

Comment: The problem then , the first "output_res" within the function must be "output_res= ....", and not "output_res+=...." otherwise I am having "global name 'output_res' is not defined"

Comment: you could have used it with output_res = recurse(output_res, left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0), if you can afford to change in "def recurse()"

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `global` command into the function and need to just make sure that the global variable is defined beforehand:

```
    output_res = ""

    def recurse(left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
        global output_res
        spacer = spacer_base * depth
        if (threshold[node] != -2):
            """print(spacer + "if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                str(threshold[node]) + " ) {")"""
            output_res += spacer + "if ( " + features[node] + " <= " + \
                str(threshold[node]) + " ) {"
            if left[node] != -1:
                recurse (left, right, threshold, features, left[node], depth+1)
            """print(spacer + "}\n" + spacer +"else {")"""
            output_res += spacer + "}\n" + spacer +"else {"
            if right[node] != -1:
                recurse (left, right, threshold, features, right[node], depth+1)
            """print(spacer + "}")"""
            output_res += spacer + "}"
        else:
            target = value[node]
            for i, v in zip(np.nonzero(target)[1], target[np.nonzero(target)]):
                target_name = target_names[i]
                target_count = int(v)
                """print(spacer + "return " + str(target_name) + " ( " + \
                    str(target_count) + " examples )")"""
                output_res += spacer + "return " + str(target_name) + " ( " + \
                    str(target_count) + " examples )"

        return 

    recurse(left, right, threshold, features, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Then, I got : global name 'output_res' is not defined
Since "output_res += spacer + "if..." and not "output_res = spacer + "if..."

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the global statement inside your function, not outside

```
output_res = ""

def recurse(left, right, threshold, features, node, depth):
    global output_res
    ...
```